# ScrapySplash javascript page won't render

Tags: python, scrapy-splash

I am self teaching myself python and I have ran into an interesting problem I have not been able to solve by myself, so I am asking you geniuses.

I am trying to render this webpage https://apps.gsccca.org/login.asp in javascript with Scrapy-Splash. The .html file I saved is not rendered in javascript, but the .png file is. I want the .html file rendered also.

```
import base64

import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "TestSpider 1"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://apps.gsccca.org/login.asp'
        splash_args = {
                'wait': 0.5,
                'html': 1,
                'png': 1,
                'width': 600,
                'render_all': 1,
        }
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.save_page, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)

    def save_page(self, response):
        filename = 'html_page.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        png_bytes = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        filename = 'some_image.png'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(png_bytes)
```

I expect the saved html_page.html should be a javascript rendered page.